# Stripe payment integration failing CSP

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

when I try to integrate stripe on to my web application, I am able to get to the card detail page. When I enter test cards and press pay now, I am getting an error that says

**refused to frame "http://localhost:3000" because it violates the following Content security policy directive "frame-src-https"**

I am using react and backend is nodeJs

Comment: Could you share some examples of your code?  It might help get a better answer.

Have you reviewed the [Stripe requirements for Content Security Policies?
https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy

Also here's a useful guide for Content Security Policy in general.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: Everything is as per defined in stripe docs. Can't figure out why?

Comment: [link] (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart) this is the code. When I ran the same code locally its giving me the same error. PLease help

Comment: These docs are not intended to be a feature complete web application, just something to get you started.  Take a look here to get started on including CSP into your React app: https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-content-security-policy-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/